# Spark executor taking too much time to process zero records batch in spark kafka streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have spark cluster deployed on Yarn(Hadoop 2.7.1).

Configuration
6 Data Node
6 Node Manager
Each with 12 vCores and 48 GB of memory

Apache Kafka - 0.10.1.1
Apache Spark - 2.0.0

My each spark application is consuming data from kafka using spark kafka streaming direct approach.

I have deployed 9 spark apps on above cluster with below configuration.

2 executors
Each with : 
6 GB memory
4 CPU cores

When i deploy all 9 apps, there is schedule delay for each application for zero records. At start scheduling delay increases for 1-2 min. then slowly it comes down to zero. Sometimes it shows processing time of 2-3 min for zero records on spark-UI.

I am not able to figure out above issue.

Note : My spark kafka streaming consumer interval is 1 second for each application.(Real time request processing)

Comment: did you find anything to reduce processing time for zero record?

Comment: We are not facing this issue since we have shifted to structured streaming api.